# Service Cloud Development what method to get the

Tags: developer-console, console, consoleintegrationtoolkit

How can I get the ID of the record regardless of the type of tab that is displaying a custom button.  For example at the minute I have a button on an Order object that gets the ID like so:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/39.0/integration.js")}

var sfdcUrlName = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;

var myParentTabId = '';

// Here evaluating a parent tab ID
var readParentId = function(result){
myParentTabId = result.id;
};

sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(readParentId);

var objID = '';
var showObjectId = function(result) {
objID = result.id;
};
sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabObjectId(showObjectId);

var openSubtab = function(result){
sforce.console.openSubtab(myParentTabId, sfdcUrlName + '/apex/VFPAGE?id=' + objID , true, 'VFPAGE',null);
};
sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(openSubtab);
```

As my visualforce page uses the Order Standard Controller (and I'd rather not change this) you may realise that if the primary Tab is not showing an Order detail ID then a visualforce error is displayed

```
Id XXXXXXXXXX is not valid for the Order standard controller
```

I know there are methods like getEnclosingTabID, getfocusedSubTab and getFocusedPrimaryTabObjectID as above and presumably I need to use a few in conjunction but whilst getEnclosingTabID gives me the focused tab id I don't know how to use this to get the record id.

I hope that makes sense.

What I am wondering is what do I use to get the ID of the record from the focused tab regardless of whether it is a primary or sub-tab?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get the record ID out of a tab via a button. But you don't necessarily know if the button will be in a primary tab or sub tab at the time it's clicked.

I would suggest a combination of getEnclosingTabID and getPageInfo methods. You feed the enclosing tab ID into the getPageInfo method which in turn gives you the info about that tab in a JSON format.

```
sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(getRecordId);

var getRecordId = function getRecordId(result) { 
    var tabId = result.id;
    sforce.console.getPageInfo(tabId, doSomething);   
} 

var doSomething = function doSomething(result) {    
    var parsedInfo = JSON.parse(result.pageInfo);
    var myObjectId = parsedInfo.objectId; 
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getenclosingtabid.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getpageinfo.htm